# Regression as a program

Tags: vba, linear-regression

What I have is a 1000+ numeric data given in excel column A. I have to take 50 (A1:A50) and another folowing 50 data (A51:A100), paste them to B and C columns and order them from lowest to highest. After that, I have to linearly regress them and find Rsquare and the regression formula. After finding the r square and formula I have to keep them somewhere to proceed to the next step which is taking the Step which is the same but this time A2:A51 and A52:A101.

I have to do this in a loop and store the results.

Comment: What is it you are having trouble with ? Your question is too broad. SO is a community that will help you with specific issues, not with finding your algorithm unless you can show that it is relevant to the SO community.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you going.

```
Public Sub RegressionAnalysis()
    Dim sample_count As Integer
    sample_count = 50

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A2") ' First row of data
    Dim i As Integer, N As Integer, j As Integer
    N = Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count ' Count rows

    Dim rx As Range, ry As Range
    i = 0: j = 0 ' data counter, output counter
    Dim slope As Double, yint As Double
    Do While i + 2 * sample_count < N
        ' Current block of data
        Set rx = r.Offset(i, 0).Resize(sample_count, 1)
        ' Next block of data
        Set ry = rx.Offset(sample_count, 0).Resize(sample_count, 1)
        ' Use built-in function for regression slope & intercept
        slope = WorksheetFunction.slope(rx, ry)
        yint = WorksheetFunction.Intercept(rx, ry)
        ' Output values to adjacent columns
        r.Offset(j, 1).Value = slope
        r.Offset(j, 2).Value = yint
        ' Increment the counters
        i = i + sample_count
        j = j + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

With results:

[image: Excel Output]

Comment: thank you for your effort :) will take a while to figure out the logic and language. a new job for me:)